# Parse a string to date of the form "yyyy"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to parse a string to year in the format "yyyy". The code snippet I use is

```
try{
        String strDate = "200323";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);

        System.out.println("The year is " + dateStr);


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Date parse exception");
    }
```

The problem is if I use a string with 4 digits, say "2003", its parsed to the year and the output is as expected "The year is Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2003". But when we give an invalid string of more than 4 digits as in the above snippet, say "200323", it does not throw a parse exception, instead it accepts the string value and the output is shown as "The year is Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 200323". Can anyone suggest a solution to either resolve this or atleast make it throw parse exception? I even tried `formatter.setLenient(false)` before parsing, but it did not show any effect. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you just pass the first 4 characters of the string? Or if the length is more than 4 throw java.text.ParseException()

Comment: `200323` is a valid year. You could truncate the string if it has more than 4 digits.

Comment: I think the problem is making the 'formatter' figure out the year.  You have to tackle the problem of figuring out what to pass for a 'valid year', for your case.  What are the cases that might break this (invalid year strings)?  Then you can clean those and pass them to be formatted

Answer (score 1):

You mean that Date range is upto 9999 than you are wrong friend

java date range is

**Start:** `Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1`

**End:** `Wed Apr 17 21:34:08 PST 292269054`

so you can't handle that.